# Angular 6 Observer - Auth called twice

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new to Observer and Http request.
My code is working actually but not elegant at all, and the problem is that the url is called twice

```
isAuthenticated() {
    let obs = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/isLoggedIn', { withCredentials: true })
    obs.pipe(
      map(data => data.json())
    ).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.user){
        let user = {
          "steam": {
            displayName: null,
            id: null,
            photo: null
          },
          "db": {

          }
        }
        // console.log(data)
        user.db = data.user.db[0]
        user.steam.displayName = data.user.displayName
        user.steam.id = data.user.id
        user.steam.photo = data.user.photos[2]
        localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user));
      }
    })
    return obs.pipe(
        map(data => !!JSON.parse(data["_body"]).success)
      )
  }
```

First, why "http://localhost:8080/api/isLoggedIn" is called twice?

Second, how to do this in a all-in one way?
I was forced to do 2 separate stuff because I'm ignorant

Answer (score 1):

You can use tap operator with no side effect on the steam and data will be passed along to map

```
obs.pipe(
  map(data => data.json()),
  tap(data => {
  if (data.user){
    let user = {
      "steam": {
        displayName: null,
        id: null,
        photo: null
      },
      "db": {

      }
    }
    // console.log(data)
    user.db = data.user.db[0]
    user.steam.displayName = data.user.displayName
    user.steam.id = data.user.id
    user.steam.photo = data.user.photos[2]
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user));
  }
}),

    map(data => !!JSON.parse(data["_body"]).success)
  )
```